# Is the application code visible to others when it is run?

Tags: python, flask

I don't want other people to see my application code.  When I host my application, will others be able to see the code that is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The code won't be viewable. Server side code is not accessible unless you give someone access or post it somewhere public.

Comment: Well server side code is on the server. So unless you give someone access to the server or post the code somewhere everyone can see it then it's not visible. There should not be any mechanism provided by the server or the code itself to return the code to someone trying to view it. If you post it in a public repository then yes someone can see it. If your website is being hosted by some service then they should not give anyone other than you access to the hosting environment.

Answer (score 1):

No, users will only see pages rendered by your application. However, if your application or hosting platform has serious vulnerabilities (e.g. [file inclusion vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability)), users could get source code or even change it. Also, your hosting provider can see your code.